# Accepts nested attributes for nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, resources and products.

In product.rb, I just define the relationship as:

```
 belongs_to :resource
```

In resource.rb, I define the relationship as:

```
has_many :products
accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, allow_destroy: true, update_only: true
```

When I try to create a resource with an associated product concurrently, with the following command:

```
Resource.create({:name => "new resource", :capacity => 20, :store_id => 1, :products_attributes => [{:name => "new product", :description => "new description"}]})
```

The :resource_id under the product model is not automatically specified. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have `update_only: true`, so it will not create a new product for that resource.

Comment: even when i remove update_only: true, the same problem happens

Comment: what exactly happens?

Comment: huh... for some reason removing the following validation rule from product.rb makes the thing work: validates :resource_id, presence: true. The resource_id now gets added....I'm not sure why this is.

Comment: Use attr_accessible :resource_id in your product model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use inverse_of, because rails will try to run the validation before exists in the database

You can find a better explanation here:

http://kueda.net/blog/2012/09/04/validates_presence_of-and-accepts_nested_attributes_for/